# Does Sphinx Search Engine support Python API officially?

Tags: python, sphinx

Does Sphinx Search Engine support Python API officially? 
I only found Python API [here](http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/api/sphinxapi.py?r=2011), but seems it was not updated for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API in general isnt under active development. Most of the new stuff is going direct to sphinxQL - that is basicly the future.

The PHP API hasnt had much updates either
http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/list?path=/trunk/api/sphinxapi.php&start=3316
that could probably be considered the canonical API reference.

Comment: Thanks, @barryhunter. I'm pretty new in Sphinx. Do I understand right that I can use sphinxQL from python code connecting to it the same way as to usual MySQL DB?

Comment: Yes. just use the mysql client available with python, sphinx pretends to be a mysql server - so can reuse client libraries. Although to be honest nothing wrong with using the API right now - its pretty feature complete. But for best future compativblity it probably is best to start of using sphinxQL instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , Python API is officially supported and it does receive updates , see http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/list?path=/trunk/api/sphinxapi.py&start=3316 .

Answer (score 1):

Official SphinxSearch API is hardly updated, but you can actually use MySQL driver/modul (e.g. pymysql). Following is an example:

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port=9301,user='',passwd='',charset='utf8',db='')
cur = db.cursor()
qry='SELECT id,weight() FROM idx_name WHERE MATCH(\'"your Query"/1\') LIMIT 10 OPTION ranker=SPH04'
cur.execute(qry);row = cur.fetchall()
print(row)
cur.close();db.close()
```